# Десериализация JSON с дублирующими полями

Tags: c#, system.text.json

Есть проблема. При чтении JSON сериализатором system.text.json, у которого дублируются название полей не происходит ошибка. Необходимо при таких случаях вызывать исключения.
Сериализатор на класс не повесить, поскольку таких классов в проекте 100500, а во вторых некоторые классы уже имеют свои сериализаторы.

```
{
  "A":1,
  "B":2,
  "C":3,
  "A":4, 
  "B":5
}
```

к примеру это должно выдавать исключение

```
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>("{\"a\":\"a\",\"a\":\"a\"}");
```

UPD: Удалил случайную запятую из примера

Answer (score 0):

Пока получилось только так. Дело в том, что если есть дубли, то строка `foreach (var key in obj)` выдаст исключение вида `An item with the same key has already been added. Key: {0} (Parameter ‘D’).` + я добавляю по какому пути. В итоге будет исключение вида `An item with the same key has already been added. Key: {0} (Parameter ‘D’). In ‘$.A.B.C’`

```
private static void CheckDuplicate(string json)
    {
        var nodes = new[] {System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonNode.Parse(json)};
        var checkKey = new HashSet<string>();
        while (nodes.Any())
        {
            var nextNodes = new List<JsonNode>();
            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                if (node is JsonObject obj)
                {
                    checkKey.Clear();
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (var key in obj)
                        {
                            if (key.Value != null)
                                nextNodes.Add(key.Value);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new JsonException(
                            $"{ex.Message}. In `{obj.GetPath()}`");
                    }
                }
                else if (node is JsonArray arr)
                {
                    nextNodes.AddRange(arr);
                }
            }
            nodes = nextNodes.ToArray();
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Ответом делать не буду, может найдётся более элегантное решение

Comment: А если словарь - часть другого объекта? А потом, двойной парсинг, это лишняя нагрузка на сервер.

Comment: @aepot этот метод проверяет все элементы в глубь. Про двойную нагрузку ответил, что, не буду делать ответом, поскольку мне это решение не очень нравится.